How to sign a pdf/a using itext
I am trying to digitally sign a PDF/A file, however, when inserting the signature with itext 7, it gives me the following error: All the fonts must be embedded. This one is not: Helvetica
The document was created in Word and converted to PDF for testing purposes and the Helvetica font is not used, so I conclude it is because it is a PDF/A document since this error does not occur with other documents.
For now I am investigating if this is possible.

It is possible. Please share your pivotal code to identify the issue.
